# How can I copy & paste (or type) file locations, instead of inefficiently clicking to it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management

Instead of accessing file location by inefficiently clicking icons (like 'Open' and 'Save as' boxes beneath), how can I copy & paste (or type) it as permitted by [some boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ5iI.png)?

[image]

Comment: @Paul Sorry; I used the wrong screenshots. I rectified; as you can see, the dialog box above precludes clicking the address bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of [Ming Slogars](https://superuser.com/users/254498/ming-slogar) answer still applies. In the image below

1. Either type the full path & file name into the 'File name' field
2. Or only type the path & click the Open/Save button to jump to the folder. Clicking the 'Open' button would jump from location `This PC` to `C:\`
3. Now you can select a file to overwrite or type a new file name.

[image: File Open dialog box]

Answer (score 1):

As @Paul mentioned in a comment, clicking the address bar will allow you to enter a text-based path. The other option (for open/save dialogs) is simply to type the full path (including the filename) into the `File name` box (e.g., `%USERNAME%\...\hope.doc` or `C:\...\hope.doc`.)

Comment: @Paul Sorry; I used the wrong screenshots. I rectified; as you can see, the dialog box above precludes clicking the address bar.