# How to maximize a window without explicit options to do so?

Tags: windows

1. What's the term for 'windows' like the following? Anything more technical than 'window'?
2. Please see the titled question. Some examples of such windows: [How do I remove and forestall all these 'SyncMaster's?](https://superuser.com/q/1297142/269574), 1st window in [How to manually type (or copy & paste) the file location, instead of accessing it by clicking?](https://superuser.com/q/1263646/269574),  [Why does my microphone's volume still automatically decrease?](https://superuser.com/q/1143778/269574)

Answer (score 1):

The type of window you are referring to is a Modal window. [Here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) are more info on that. To expand I will quote Matt from the UX stack site.

> A modal dialog is a window that forces the user to interact with it
>   before they can go back to using the parent application. A great
>   example of this would be a prompt for saving, or the "open file"
>   dialog.

Generally if you want to maximize a window that does not have a button for it, you can try <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>. If the window itself can actually be maximized, it will be then.

Comment: There's also software available that can force the shape of any window regardless if it can be resized or not.

Comment: @LPChip Please elaborate?

Comment: I use ActualTools Window Manager (not free) and it can do this. I'm pretty sure there are other tools available that allow you to alter the size of a window based on rules you program into the settings of the application.